# Func delegate as a constructor parameter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, delegates

Trying to get my head round using delegates.

I have a class `synchronise.cs` takes two collections of different types and edits them. The collections are held in another other `viewModel` class. I've written a constructor which takes two `Func` delegates as parameters in `synchronise.cs`:

```
 public Synchronise(
     Func<IEnumerable<T> , IEnumerable<S>> MappingStoT,
     Func<IEnumerable<S>, IEnumerable<T>> MappingTtoS )
 {

 }
```

I'm then trying to new up a `Synchronise` object in my ViewModel and pass two methods with the collections as parameters:

```
this.mySynchroniser = new Synchronise<IBindableData, object>(MappingStoT(CollectionA), MappingTtoS(CollectionB));
```

Finally my two methods:

```
 public IEnumerable<CollectionA> MappingStoT(IEnumerable<CollectionB> CollectionForEdit)
 {
     var query = blah blah
     return query;
 }

 public IEnumerable<CollectionB> MappingTtoS(IEnumerable<CollectionA> CollectionForEdit)
 {
      var query = Blah blah
      return query;
 }
```

I'm getting `not assignable to parameter type` on my new `Synchronizer`. Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: Exact error should tell types that don't match....

Comment: Also consider adding class declaration (`class Synchronise<T,S.... ` in addition to constructor) - `new Synchronise` looks like it is missing  types.

Comment: Your constructor is expecting a method that takes a sequence and returns a sequence.  You're passing in a sequence, instead of such a method.  That is exactly what the error message is telling you, and it's exactly right.

Comment: edited to reflect <T>& <S>

Comment: @Servey, I'm passing it a method call. So how would you new up the Syncronise object & pass in the parameters?

Comment: @Hardgraf No, you're *not* passing the method.  You're passing the result of invoking the method.  To pass the method you just pass the method.  You can look up any example usage of delegates to see examples of this, if you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor expects `Func`s, and not the result of a method call. Try this:

```
class CollectionA { }
class CollectionB { }

class Synchronise<T, S>
{
    public static Synchronise<CollectionB, CollectionA> Create()
    {
        return new Synchronise<CollectionB, CollectionA>(MappingStoT, MappingTtoS);
    }

    public Synchronise(Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<S>> MappingStoT, Func<IEnumerable<S>, IEnumerable<T>> MappingTtoS)
    {

    }
    public static IEnumerable<CollectionA> MappingStoT(IEnumerable<CollectionB> CollectionForEdit)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<CollectionB> MappingTtoS(IEnumerable<CollectionA> CollectionForEdit)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```